# How to clear cart on every new client's session

Tags: authentication, session, cart, odoo-16

In odoo 16, my customers wonder why they still get the content of the cart they habe abandonned few days ago.

How to reset the cart content on every new login ?

Can we set this parameter revive="FALSE" in Settings ?

```py
#addons module website_sale>controllers/main.py:

class WebsiteSale(http.Controller):
#...
#...

    @http.route(['/shop/cart'], type='http', auth="public", website=True, sitemap=False)
    def cart(self, access_token=None, revive='', **post):
        """
        Main cart management + abandoned cart revival
        access_token: Abandoned cart SO access token
        revive: Revival method when abandoned cart. Can be 'merge' or 'squash'
        """
```

...or is it necessary to call this existing function on each login ?

```py
#addons module website_sale>controllers/main.py:


class WebsiteSale(http.Controller):
#...
#...
@http.route(['/shop/cart/clear'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
    def clear_cart(self):
        order = request.website.sale_get_order()
        for line in order.order_line:
            line.unlink()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it this way:

```py
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    def _reset_cart(self):
        """ reset cart content if sol older than one hour  """
        order = request.website.sale_get_order()
        dt_last_hour = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=1)
        for line in order.order_line.filtered(lambda rec: rec.create_date<dt_last_hour):
            line.unlink()

    def _cart_update(self, product_id=None, line_id=None, add_qty=0, set_qty=0, **kwargs):
        """ hook cart_update to reset cart content if sol older than one hour  """
        
        self.sudo()._reset_cart()
        res_super = super(SaleOrder, self)._cart_update(product_id, line_id, add_qty, set_qty, **kwargs)
        
        return res_super
```